# Formatting concatenated text in Excel

Tags: excel, formatting, string-concatenation

We are trying to concatenate text from two cells into one cell.

However, the text from the 1st cell needs to be BOLD.

The text from the 2nd cell needs to be regular text.

We cannot use macros.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you can't have half the text in a cell bold and half of it not.  It's just not possible.

Comment: Yes... you can manually highlight and format (bold, italics, color, etc.) a part of a string in a cell differently from the rest of the string. I want to do it automatically when concatenating two strings... Make one bold and one regular text in the same cell

Comment: You're right - you learn something every day. Apologies. According to this page: http://www.computing.net/answers/office/bold-text-in-a-cell-using-a-formula/9946.html : "There are no built-in functions that will change the format of a single word within a cell. You would need to use VBA."   Sorry I can't help further.